# Circular gradient

Tags: ios, objective-c, gradient, quartz-2d

I have searched and searched and I cannot seem to find the code that will give me the effect in the screen shot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPAiA.png

I have managed to draw the circle and get a simple top to bottom gradient working but I cannot fathom how to get the below, all help is much appreciated.

Here is what got me a simple top to bottom gradient:

```
CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, NULL, 2);
CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
CGContextClip(context);

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;

CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
```

Answer (score 3):

So you want a radial gradient. But you are drawing a linear gradient. That's pretty silly. Draw a radial gradient if you want a radial gradient!

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextDrawRadialGradient

Another possibility (considerably simpler) is to draw the radial gradient using a CIFilter:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIRadialGradient

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, however going down the Radialgradient route, I can successfully get drawrect to fulfil a radial gradient in my view, but then loses my circle that I have drawn. I cannot work out why its doing this